# Using MFC and ATL libraries without Visual Studio

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

My question is if I can use MFC and ATL libraries that come with PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2, without Visual Studio. I mean only at the command prompt with BCC32.exe or CL.exe?

I have found MFC and ATL libraries in the PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2 but I does not know if these libraries can be used without Visual Stuio IDE! What I need to do before using MFC and ATL at the command prompt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have all the headers, and either the source code or compiled version of the rest, then yes it can be used without Visual Studio. Visual Studio is just an IDE that invokes the compiler etc. for you. With command line tools you do that job yourself.

Here's a minimal MFC program that you can try out:

```
#define WINVER  0x0500      // Windows 2000 and up.
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components

typedef CFrameWnd   MainWindow;

class App
    : public CWinApp
{
private:
    bool createTheMainWindow()
    {
        static char const title[]   = "A general top level MFC window";
        MainWindow* const pWnd      =
            new MainWindow;
        if( !pWnd ) { return false; }   // Pre-standard 'new' in MFC...
        m_pMainWnd = pWnd;
        pWnd->Create( NULL, title );
        return true;
    }

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();

        if( !createTheMainWindow() ) { return false; }

        m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow( SW_SHOW );
        m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
        return true;
    }
};

App theApp;
```

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Thanks Sir Alf P. Steinbach. Now it is clear to me that MFC and ATL include files and lib files can be used without Visual Studio IDE. Thanks for your great help!

Comment: One thing that I specifically want to ask that is there a good book about on MFC or ATL in which, specifically examples are compiled with bcc32.exe or cl.exe! Please suggest me if you have some knowledge about it.

Comment: The above example compiles and works fine with recent versions of Visual C++ (the [cl.exe] compiler). I'm not sure, but I *suspect* that the only generally available version of [bcc32.exe], the Borland compiler, is like 5.0 or something from the mid 1990's. If so then that compiler is probably unable to deal with recent MFC.

Comment: Ok I tried to compile your example with cl.exe. There is only error message comes out that "afxmsg_.h" include file could not be opened! Could you please suggest me where can I find "afxmsg_.h" file?

Comment: @Shahid: apparently an installation of Visual Studio Express creates a directory with some MFC headers, but lacking much including the file that you mention, as reported [over at Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/118ca5b7-c96d-4eed-bd94-d6ac42ad0186/). Possibly it's the same with PSDK Windows Server 2003 R2. In a way it's understandable, since Microsoft wants to keep moving on to new "technologies" all the time and selling the tools for that...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, since some functionality relies on the Visual Studio compiler specific behavior. For example the way trampolines are used to map window handles to objects.

I'm assuming that you by "can be used without Visual Stuio IDE" you actually mean "with another compiler", since you mention the Borland compiler. Of course you can write C++ in a text editor and compile those files from the command line, not using the IDE, but what you want is using another compiler, right? (the IDE and the compiler are related but not the same).